# Simplifying this ArcTan sum expression

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

```
$Assumptions = Element[t, Reals] && Element[ω, Reals] && ω > 0 
&& t > 0;
ArcTan[8.54596*10^7 (1. + 1. t^2 ω^2) (1.2214 + E^ω Cos[
2 ArcTan[t ω]]), -1.70919*10^8 E^ω t ω] + 
ArcTan[8.54596*10^7 (1. + 1. t^2 ω^2) (1.2214 + E^ω 
Cos[2ArcTan[t ω]]),1.70919*10^8 E^ω t ω]//FullSimplify
```

Mathematica doesn't simplify this seemingly `ArcTan[x,y]+ArcTan[x,-y]` expression.
I plotted the 3D-graph, it shows the expression is zero for all values of `t` and `\[Omega]`.

I understand one underlying reason might be Mathematica isn't sure about the positivity of `Cos` term in `x`, and hence, `x`. Am I right? Any ideas to simplify this term in code, instead of manually, would be very much appreciated. I'm relatively new to the language.

Comment: Maybe `Simplify[expr, Cos[2 ArcTan[t \[Omega]]] > 0]`, where `expr` is your expression involving `Arctan`? You can use the second argument of `Simplify` to submit assumptions.

Comment: The Cos term does not necessarily have to be greater than zero. And, I have tried out inserting the global assumptions inside Simplify and FullSimply but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If `(1.2214 + E^\[Omega] Cos[2 ArcTan[t \[Omega]]])` is not always greater than zero, then it's not necessarily true that the `ArcTan` terms sum to zero.  (Consider `x < 0`, `y == 0`.)

Answer (score 1):

First you should avoid using inexact numbers if possible.

```
expr = ArcTan[ α (1 +  t^2 ω^2) (γ +E^ω Cos[2 ArcTan[t ω]]), -β E^ω t ω] + 
  ArcTan[α(1 +  t^2 ω^2) (γ + E^ω Cos[2 ArcTan[t ω]]), β E^ω t ω]
```

Now, with assumptions inside , the simplification evaluates as you expect

```
Simplify[expr, 
Assumptions -> {ω > 0,t > 0 , α > 0, β > 0, γ >0,Cos[2 ArcTan[t ω]] > 0,Elements[{ω, t, α, β,γ}, Reals]}]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Your solution does simplify it to 0, because you're assuming Cos[2 ArcTan[t ω]] > 0. I don't see any good reason to assume so. If you do, please let me know.

Comment: @ naeema18: In the question I read `... about the positivity of Cos term..  ` as an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Assumptions = ω > 0 && t > 0;
```

Note that if a variable is positive it is redundant to add that it is real.

If you want exact results you must use exact numbers. Use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
expr = ArcTan[
     8.54596*10^7 (1. + 1. t^2 ω^2) (1.2214 + 
        E^ω Cos[
          2 ArcTan[t ω]]), -1.70919*10^8 E^ω t ω] + 
    ArcTan[8.54596*10^7 (1. + 1. t^2 ω^2) (1.2214 + 
        E^ω Cos[2 ArcTan[t ω]]), 
     1.70919*10^8 E^ω t ω] // Rationalize;
```

[`TrigToExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) is what you need

```
expr // TrigToExp // Simplify

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: If you plot `Plot3D[TrigToExp[ArcTan[x, y] + ArcTan[x, -y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` you can see that the comment from  `Michael E2` concerning the first argument x stll holds.